# Central password storage tool that multiple users can access with privilege levels

Tags: password, password-management

Working in web development I am in charge of a large array of passwords for various servers, CMSs, etc, etc. At the moment these are stored on paper in a safe, which is cumbersome and an enormous list.

Often my colleagues will also need access to various aspects of the various systems. But of course there are some things only certain people should see.  Not all staff accessing it will be server admins some are account managers who just need to be able to login to a CMS to edit a webpage for example.

So I am looking for suggestions of a system that will facilitate this centralisation and safe sharing of passwords. Do you know of anything particularly awesome in this area?

The technology it is based on is not all together important as we run both Windows and Linux servers in the office. Also I would prefer an open source solution, but paid for is fine as well.

Currently [PasswordState](http://www.clickstudios.com.au/) is looking like the front runner so any comments on that would also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trialling [LastPass Enterprise](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php). I figure the easier it is for users to use the less likely they are to end up writing down passwords or copying them into their clipboards etc. It is certainly not the cheapest alternative and does involve relying on and sharing with a third party.

Still just in the trialling stage and still on the look out for an option with a better user interface and individual password expiry. Its integration into the browser is pretty killer though.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend looking into [Secret Server](http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html).  It has the features your looking for plus logging and isn't very expensive.  If you prefer open source and free check out [Webkeepass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkeepass).  We started using Webkeepass but switched to Secret Server as it's much more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you could use SSH-keys then you can leave your passwords in the safe. A SSH key for every people is unique. Then you could write a small script which connect to the server and write the ".authorized_keys" with your defined keys. Then you have a centrilized place where you can insert the keys and they are replicated to all servers.

PasswortState is cool but when you need only a simple solution its enough with a script on linux.

The most common way when you have Windows Server you can use a domain. When the server is in the domain you can login with the domain admin then you have one account with one password. But for Windows are here people who know better about this.

Edit: There is a tool that is called "[Alle meine Passwörter](http://www.alle-meine-passworte.de/)" its german but you can make a file on a server and people can open the file and edit. There you can categorize your Passwords. The file is encrypted.

Comment: We do run keys on all the linux servers and we do make use of Windows domains etc. This is more for MySQL connection details, FTP login details for old servers or client machines etc. Not all staff accessing it will be server admins some are account managers who just need to be able to login to a CMS to edit a webpage for example/

Comment: Ah ok ;) very usefull information. You should edit your question. Then is something like PasswordState very cool. Or you as web developer write a short system. @Treffynnon